# Child Component in React (Meteor) not firing events

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

folks.   I'm a relatively new Meteor developer, and after learning Blaze, I decided to start learning React, because it seemed like the right thing to do, and I sort of liked the idea of how it worked.

Anyway, I'm having issues with a bit of code I'm working on, and could use some guidance...  I've got the following segments of code:

https://gist.github.com/czbaker/2101526219eea5330553

For some reason, when the form in the  component is submitted, it isn't firing the function that's meant to handle submission.  Instead, it refreshes the page (as `event.preventDefault()` never happens).

What would be causing this to happen?   As per suggested on IRC, I've tried replacing `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` with the following:

- `onSubmit={()=>{this.handleSubmit}}`
- `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}`

Neither of them had any effect, the form submission function still isn't being called.  I'm really confused, because I followed documentation for the most part, and it looks like it should be working.

As I'm really new to React, I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but have no idea what.  Can anyone offer me some aid?  Thanks in advance!

The current project is also in a BitBucket repository, for those who need it https://bitbucket.org/czbaker/karuto/

All I've been able to figure out so far is that if I render the problem component by itself (not as a child of another component) using ReactLayout, it works fine, but the second that I try to render it as a child component (doing it the way it's shown in MDG's Todos tutorial (React version), events refuse to fire, yet there's no errors.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think that the main issue is that you are trying to render the entire html tree using React. Try to change your layout to just a div and handle the `title` changes in a different way (possibly using a global `state` or a `ReactiveVariable`).

Comment: You were 100% correct.  I got rid of the title code and swapped to using `componentDidMount` and `document.title` as a temporarily hackish solution, and all is well.  If you post this comment as a solution, I'll select it as the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to render the entire HTML tree using React.

If you are using `flow-router` and `react-layout`, you can simply render the document fragment that you desire and it will be placed in a designated root node which id is `'react-root'`.

Otherwise, I would suggest using [static-html](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/static-html) if you don't need blaze and create a root element for React:

some_file.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
</body>
```

and then render the root component into it using your preferred router.

Then, change the `title` dynamically via a `ReactiveVar` or some other method.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Been bashing my head against this issue for half a day, didn't even think about the whole issue of rendering the whole HTML tree breaking stuff.  I'm quite new to React.

Answer (score 0):

I am using React with React Router, alongside Google's MDL, and had the same issue (as well as a few others, such as navigating to different routes would cause a full page reload).

When attempting to find the cause, I found that removing the MDL classes from the the div surrounding `{this.props.children}` in my parent component resulted in the event listeners firing correctly.

After investigating, it appears that this is due to the way that MDL structures the DOM nodes, and can be resolved by either calling `componentHandler.upgradeDOM()` in each child component's `componentDidUpdate()` method, as follows:

```
App = React.createClass({
 render() {
   return(
    <div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
     ...
       <div className="mdl-layout__content">
        { this.props.children }
       </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
});


ChildComponent = React.createClass({
 handleClick() {
   alert("I've been clicked!");
 },
 render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <button onClick={this.handleClick} 
         className="mdl-button mdl-js-button">Click Me</button>
     </div>
  );
 },
componentDidUpdate() {
  componentHandler.upgradeDOM();
},
});
```

As outlined here, http://quaintous.com/2015/07/09/react-components-with-mdl/; or by using a *'patched'* version of MDL, like the one here:
https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl

I know this is a little different to the OP's issue, but I figured I'd add this here in the hopes that it helps someone else with this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my Layout.jsx i changed

```
export default class extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return(
       <body>
         ...some jsx
       </body>
     );
   }
}
```

to

```
export default class extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return(
       <div>
         ...some jsx
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```

and it helps, now the React events are working fine